# increase popen2 buffer size in GNU Octave

Tags: octave

Is it possible to increase the buffer used in popen2 between Octave and the subprocess? It looks like the buffer is limited to approximately 66560 Bytes. This snippet shows the problem:

```
## This works with s = 65
## but not with s = 66
s = 66;
[in, out, pid] = popen2 ("dd", {"if=/dev/urandom",
                                "bs=1K",
                                sprintf("count=%i", s)});
pause (1);
[vt, cnt] = fread(out);
assert (cnt, s * 1024);
waitpid (pid);
fclose (in);
fclose (out);
```

returns:

```
66+0 Datensätze ein
66+0 Datensätze aus
67584 Bytes (68 kB) kopiert, 0.999523 s, 67.6 kB/s
error: ASSERT errors for:  assert (cnt,s * 1024)

  Location  |  Observed  |  Expected  |  Reason
     ()         66560        67584       Abs err 1024 exceeds tol 0
```